# How to get all the available methods for a object in Pycharm (for ex. Pygame)

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Please have a check on the screenshot,
[image]

In that here self.image has got the pygame.image.load() method on it. but if i have to access all the available methods to self.image object, Pycharm autosuggestions does not list those.

Actually, self.image has got the get_rect to display the rectangle property of the image.

self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.
```

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language, which means that the object type is known at execution time and not before. Therefore the auto-complete function may not work fine. Some proposals are made by analyzing your code statically.

Comment: @tangoal In that case, referring to the documentation is the only solution to use the methods effectively.
for example:
[https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load]
**
how to understand what are the objects returned to this variable in runtime, in my case, pygame.image.load has been invoked, documentation does not list all the methods that could be used.

**

Comment: You also just can open the external module in your IDE to view all method names.

Comment: @tangoal thats a cool idea. so here self.image is an object of surface class and when i click the getrect() method, surface.py opens and the method is an empty one just got the pass declared under it. 

`self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`

Answer (score 4):

If Pycharm isn't giving you good suggestions, that's because it can't figure out what you're looking at. Python is duck typed. What a function takes or returns could be any type. But maybe you already know what it is. Pycharm's suggestions get better if you add [type annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) for your functions or variables. Use <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> when your cursor is on a function or variable declaration to add type hints.

You can also use <kbd>F1</kbd> to get help for the item under the cursor and you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on a variable to jump to where it was defined.